# WebAuthn development on localhost

Tags: navigator, webauthn

- I'm trying to develop website authentication using WebAuthn. Unfortunately I've run into a problem. When calling navigator.credentials.create I get the following error:

  SecurityError: The relying party ID 'https://localhost:7000' is not a registrable domain suffix of, nor equal to 'https://localhost:7000'.

Does this really mean I cannot develop WebAuthn from localhost? I'm using Chrome70 beta by the way. 
Seems kinda insane that I have to develop on a real domain, debugging and development would become a nightmare.

Any ideas about this? Is localhost really forbidden in WebAuthn?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "http://localhost:7000", without https?

Comment: Hi @grzuy  - the solution was just to use "localhost"  and not port number or protocol.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. I think the browser still allows localhost with a specific port, if your server is listening on that port of course.

Comment: @Spock were you able to get authentication to work on localhost?

Comment: @johnnyodonnell yes! it's a long time ago now but I managed to get it to work..  I'm actually planning on dusting off my code (refactor etc) and I think the entire webauthn is much more stabile now.. we're using it in production

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to get rid of this error message:

- You don't set the RP ID in the options. In this case it will use the current domain, which is `localhost`
- Or you set the RP ID to a valid domain as per the [URL specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-domain-string) i.e. no scheme, no port, no user, no password, no path and in this case it is also `localhost`

More information about the RP ID in the [Webauthn specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#rp-id)

Comment: yep, this solved the issue literally `res.rp.id = 'localhost';` and to think I was going to try to setup ngrok

Comment: this is the correct answer