# iOS Capacitor App Can't make connection to WebAuthn Server (RP ID Security Error)

Tags: ios, xcode, spring-boot, http, capacitor

I have a capacitor app that makes http calls to my webauthn server which has https domain.  When I run the capacitor iOS app in the Xcode simulator during the registration process, I get an error that states:

"SecurityError: The provided RP ID is not a registrable domain suffix of the effective domain of the document".

I don't exectly know what this means but I am wondering if it has anything to do with the fact that the capacitor app is run on capacitor://localhost and my server has its own https domain?

What can I do to resolve this error?

I tried different methods of making the http calls but right now I don't think that is the issue since I can see that the first of the 2 http calls has 200 response.  It just never makes it to the second endpoint.  I am kind of lost here.  All of the routing works from our web interface on our springboot server btw, just not from the capacitor ios app.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to a problem with the configuration of the WebAuthn server. I'm no expert on your setup but it seems you are sending an RP ID that is not configured in the WebAuthn server.

So, either you are sending it with the protocol/scheme (capacitator://) or it is misconfigured on the server side. It should be just `localhost` on both sides.

Comment: So it should be localhost on the serverside even if it is not a localhost?  Right now the RP ID on the server side is showing up as its domain name.

Comment: It is my understanding that the client should send its domain and the server should accept it. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52870513/webauthn-development-on-localhost